# Is there a way to check a list of variables to determine which one is largest?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, but I have three variables, and I want to determine which one is the largest, is there a way to put the variables into an array, or some easier way to determine which is largest?

The goal is to have the clients ask a number of questions, and with each question it increments the corresponding variable. You will notice on the link below if you test it. Once it determines which variable is largest, it will then do a document write to a span id.

I have searched, but have not found much on this.

http://www.sprayfoamsys.com/cmsdev/index.php?page=rig-constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the link you've provided, it looks like the `Math.max` solution provided by others isn't actually what you want, since you don't want to know the *value* of the largest variable, but rather *which* variable is the largest.  The most straightforward (and most readable) way of doing this is:

```
if (a >= b && a >= c) {
    document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML("Plan A is the best.");
} else if (b >= a && b >= c) {
    document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML("Plan B is the best.");
} else {
    document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML("Plan C is the best.");
}
```

*Note that it is entirely possible for the user to end up with a tie, given the quiz format you've provided.*

Answer (score 5):

When you say "largest" i will assume you want to compare for the greatest numeric value, which is as simple as:

```
largest = Math.max(a, b, c);
```

There may be some type coercion needed, as `Math.max` expects numeric values:

```
a = 'foo100';
b = 'foo200';
c = 'foo300';
largest = Math.max(a, b, c);
```

In this case, `largest` will be `NaN` because none of the values were numbers. For this example you could use:

```
r = /\D/g;
largest = Math.max(a.replace(r, ''), b.replace(r, ''), c.replace(r, ''));
//largest == 300
```

For suffixed values, such as `30px`, you could use `parseInt`

---

If you need to know which variable was largest, you can compare the largest value with the original vars:

//These are two short examples that don't scale very well, but work great for <5 items

```
if (largest === a) {
  //a
} else if (largest === b) {
  //b
} else if (largest === c) {
  //c
}

switch (largest) {
  case a:
    //a
    break;
  case b:
    //b
    break;
  case c:
    //c
    break;
}
```

Comment: It looks like he wants to know which variable is the largest (e.g. `a`, `b`, or `c`) and not the value of the largest variable.

Answer (score 1):

The "Math.max()" function can be passed any number of arguments, and it'll return the largest.  If what you want, therefore, is the *value* of the largest in a list, then that should do it.

Also note that "do a document.write()" is not how you update a page. Calling "document.write()" after the page has completed its initial rendering will obliterate it. Instead, what you'll want to do is find the `<span>` by its "id" value and then set its "innerHTML":

```
 var theSpan = document.getElementById("the-id-of-the-span");
 theSpan.innerHTML = largestValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of finding the index and value of the largest array item, which may come in handy if you abstract your code to handle *n* options.

```
var largest = -99999; // something less than the largest
var largestIndex = -1; // an invalid array index
var check = [4, -2, 0.11023, 100, 500];

for (var i=0; i < check.length; i++) {
  if (check[i] > largest) {
    largest = check[i];
    largestIndex = i;
  }
}

alert('the largest was item ' + largestIndex + ' with a value of ' + largest);
```